# My y axis keeps changing whenever I code the data labels for my boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, yaxis

I'm trying to code a boxplot and the axis needs to be between -100 and 500, I've set the limits and it works fine when I run it but whenever I run the next bit of my code to code the data labels the y axis automatically changes:

[image: image with set y axis limits]

[image: image after I've coded the data labels]

I've been using this code:

```
p+scale_x_discrete(name="Time intervals") +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Tumour volume change (%)" , limits = c(-100,500))  
  
p + geom_text(data = tumourvolume, aes(y=Volume+1.85 , label = Volume), 
            position = position_dodge(width=0.5) , size=2)
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput` and your complete code for the graph?

Comment: Try with assigning your code back to `p`, i.e. try `p <- p + scale_y_continuous(....)`.

Comment: ^... or add `+` like `limits = c(-100,500)) +` and continue the next line starting with `+ geom_tile(....`

Answer (score 0):

Both code blocks are referencing the same base plot code (`p`).  Therefore, the following code block:

```
p+scale_x_discrete(name="Time intervals") +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Tumour volume change (%)" , limits = c(-100,500))  
  
p + geom_text(data = tumourvolume, aes(y=Volume+1.85 , label = Volume), 
            position = position_dodge(width=0.5) , size=2)
```

Will create two plots in succession: one which applies the `scale_` functions, and one which adds the text values.  If the intention is to create one plot to include `scale_` functions *and* add the text geom, use one of the following:

```
# CODE OPTION 1: all one block
p + scale_x_discrete(name="Time intervals") +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Tumour volume change (%)" , limits = c(-100,500)) + 
  geom_text(data = tumourvolume, aes(y=Volume+1.85 , label = Volume), 
            position = position_dodge(width=0.5) , size=2)

# CODE OPTION 2: reassign p mid-block
p <- p + scale_x_discrete(name="Time intervals") +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Tumour volume change (%)" , limits = c(-100,500))  
  
p + geom_text(data = tumourvolume, aes(y=Volume+1.85 , label = Volume), 
            position = position_dodge(width=0.5) , size=2)
```